# Swift: dismissViewController and Instantiate another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, instantiation, dismiss

I am trying to dismiss a view controller and present a another one at the same time. When the `Level1Controller()` is done and calls the `self.dismissViewController()`, I would like it to take me to a different view controller called `EndScene()`.

This is the code that has gotten me the closest.

```
   self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {() -> Void in
       let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       let nextViewConroller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("endscene")
       self.presentViewController(nextViewConroller, animated: false, completion: nil)
   })
```

Comment: And what is the actual issue you are experiencing @Rogue Studios?

Comment: @RaphaelOliveira It will just boot me back to the root viewcontroller and this is the error message `2015-12-23 17:47:35.333 Spin Game[6466:2789372] Warning: Attempt to present <Spin_Game.EndScene: 0x14edc0b20> on <Spin_Game.Level1Controller: 0x14f86d400> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Comment: Got it, will write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated` on `Level1Controller`, call it on the view controller that presented it. Then on the completion block you can present the `EndScene` in the same way you are doing. The error happens because in fact since you removed `Level1Controller` from the window it doesn't make sense to use it to present another view controller.

Window -> ParentViewController (call dismiss here) -> Level1Controller

Window -> ParentViewController (present EndScene on completion) -> EndScene

You will probably have to notify the parent of `Level1Controller` that the cancel action was performed and you can do that by delegate. Another option (I didn't test it) is to keep the dismissal in `Level1Controller` and present from the `presentingViewController`.

```
self.presentingViewController.presentViewController...
```

Not sure though if `presentingViewController` will be nil when the completion block is invoked.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this soon. Ill let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hey Rogue, I'm glad you solved your issue. Which solution you ended up using?